# always failed to send image using telegram API using PHP

Tags: php, file, telegram-bot

I want to make a function to send an image using Telegram API (reference API: https://github.com/mgp25/Telegram-Bot-API/), but when I try to run this, I always get an error like this:

> Message: file_get_contents(''): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Here is my code [updated]:

```
<?php

require 'Telegram.php';

$tele = new telegramBot('token');
//$info = $tele->sendMessage('218945828',"wadaw");
$url= 'image/maldini.jpg';
$info = $tele->sendPhoto('chatid',$url);
print_r($info);

?>
```

error :

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/sendPhoto?chat_id=chat_id&photo=0): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgp25\Telegram-Bot-API-master\src\Telegram.php on line 465

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have SSL connection with Telegram? If you did not have SSL connection with telegram, non of telegram commands will not work but if you can send just a simple  message so there is no SSL problem.
After all if everything is OK except image,use this cURL code except using that ready to use `telegramBOT` class.
if this is not working (cURL) , so there is really problem in reading from or finding photo on your server(Real server or xampp folder or so on...)
If it is server(host) it MUST be upload first and if it is xampp image must be in true folder. it is better to test if image is accessible (for example via http://localhost/image/maldini.jpg from webbrowser?

cURL Ready to use code for sending photo:

```
$BOT_TOKEN='1231325:AbXDECcvhir7'; //----YOUR BOT TOKEN
$chat_id=123456 // or '123456' ------Receiver chat id
define('BOTAPI','https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $BOT_TOKEN .'/');

$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath('image/maldini.jpg'), 'image/jpg', 'maldini.jpg'); //first parameter is YOUR IMAGE path
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id , 
        'photo' => $cfile
        ];

    $ch = curl_init(BOTAPI.'sendPhoto');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: i think this is problem with reading from or finding photo on my xampp server. i have copy paste your code but still doesn't work. do you have advice?

Comment: My Code is completley tested and is working flawlessly( except you must use your own token and chat id and accessible image path).Question: Is image accessible via web-browser? if it is ok then you should tune your code. play with your address, and correct any typos.

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH on line 7 you MUST NOT use `http://` link format. Use `.....realpath('image/maldini.jpg'), .......` instead. 'realpath` function is also case sansetive or insensitive due to platform it is runnig from, so always it is better to use similar case chararters in file name and path. Secondly, I said to check that file in your WEB-BROWSER(chrome,firefox,IE,and so on) to see if file accessible ? Does `http://localhost/image/maldini.jpg` link show an image from firefox(for example)?

Comment: I am glad too friend.

Comment: Hi Mr,Tick Tock. would you help me again? i have little problem when implement sendimage function in codeigniter. i was create new threade here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413381/get-blank-page-result-when-using-send-image-function-telegram-api-on-codeigniter big big big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think urlencode('http://127.0.0.1/mgp25/maldini.jpg'); is the problem. You should use your provider/public IP address. Or use a relative path.

Comment: hello friends. i have update the code and get error notice like above.