# sending message in telegram bot using curl

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I want to get my bot message from database and send to the user, It worked when my text was only 1 word,but now it doesn't work and shows the HTTP BAD REQUEST 400. I think I should use curl, but I didn't find any document useful for sending a long message from telegram bot.(actually because I'm a beginner in php)

here is my code

```
$botToken="something";
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;


$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, true);

$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message = $update["message"]["text"];

define("dbhost", "localhost:3306"); define("dbuser", "sm");
define("dbpass", "sm"); define("database", "sm");

switch ($message){
 case "/get":
  connected($chatID);

break;

 }

function sendMessage($chatID,$message){


$url =$GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$message;

//file_get_contents($url);
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

   //checkJSON($chatID,$update);

 }

 function connected($chatID){

 $conn = mysql_connect(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass);

 if(! $conn )
 {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }


  mysql_select_db( database );

  $strSQL = "SELECT text FROM bott WHERE id= '1' ";
  $result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $message=$row['text'];
  sendMessage($chatID,$message);
  mysql_close($conn);
  }




function checkJSON($chatID,$update){

    $myFile = "log.txt";
    $updateArray = print_r($update,TRUE);
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $chatID ."\n\n");
    fwrite($fh, $updateArray."\n\n");
    fclose($fh);
  }




?>
```

this is the error when I use file_get_contents

```
[08-Jul-2016 12:27:35 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:     file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot218048829:AAF7baKISagQfALp4OIPh-   yU_hMOnpFGU0A/sendMessage?   chat_id=98506693&amp;text=Introduction%0D%0AA+COMPUTER+PROCESSOR+such+as+Intel%92s+i486+used+to+cost+around+the+same+as+a+small+car.+Nowadays+a+chip+with+similar+power+is+the+price+of+a+chocolate+bar.%0D%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in /home/sfduiir1/public_html/php.php on line 29
```

This code doesn't send anything to the user.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? Are any errors showing?

Comment: yes, here is the report of this code

Comment: @Script47     [08-Jul-2016 12:05:36 America/Chicago] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/sfduiir1/public_html/php.php on line 44
[08-Jul-2016 12:05:36 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant website - assumed 'website' in /home/sfduiir1/public_html/php.php on line 27

Comment: and when I used file_get_contents ..It was the error    [08-Jul-2016 12:27:35 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot218048829:AAF7baKISagQfALp4OIPh-yU_hMOnpFGU0A/sendMessage?chat_id=98506693&amp;text=Introduction%0D%0AA+COMPUTER+PROCESSOR+such+as+Intel%92s+i486+used+to+cost+around+the+same+as+a+small+car.+Nowadays+a+chip+with+similar+power+is+the+price+of+a+chocolate+bar.%0D%0A): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 in /home/sfduiir1/public_html/php.php on line 29    @Script47

Comment: but message text is not empty

Comment: Try to utf8 encode the text message

Comment: And be aware of never make public real api Keys and sensible data on your code examples

Comment: how can I change it to utf8? @Edu

Comment: actually this is for test and I will change it. thanks for your attention @Edu

Comment: utf8_encode($message) http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I have the same error! Bad request @Edu

Comment: I found this issue and it said "this problem is a telegram bug"! https://github.com/eljojo/telegram_bot/issues/19

Comment: Try utf8_encode(url_encode($message))

Comment: why do you think this error is from encoding? @Edu

Comment: Because testing your url and changing **&amp;text=** by **&text=** I've got a 400 error about message not being utf8 encoded

Comment: Does your host support SSL?

Comment: I answered your question. IMHO, first send only message,and when it worked fine than add other codes like interacting with databse. In this way troubleshootig is simple and your  coding will be fast.

Comment: thank you @Edu , I changed the url to utf8 using          urlencode(utf8_encode($message))

Comment: @TickTock yeah I used to go step by step for debugging the code, but I didn't know what to do with this problem.

Comment: @Mohammadb yeah, It supports ssl.

Comment: @TickTock actually  It didn't solve my problem. I used this code urlencode(utf8_encode($message)) and it is working.

Comment: So then, what is your real problem?

Comment: @TickTock   It was for message encoding, the error was from this line $url =$GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($message);
 file_get_contents($url);    because I didn't convert my message to utf8

Comment: OK, that's right. Telegram receives and sends ALL messages in utf-8 format.[All queries must be made using UTF-8](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests)

Answer (score 11):

In curl method you should NOT use any data in url.
as you see your url that get error has spaces that is not valid.
 This is a working curl code:

```
$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$chatId=1234567;  //Receiver Chat Id 
$params=[
    'chat_id'=>$chatID,
    'text'=>'MoonLight',
];
$ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: hi sir, do you have a reference when send image using curl? i always get notice : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH It was better to ask as a new question, for you and others that have same question. But as you requested i wrote some sample code .This is its link: [How to send photo with cURL](https://eval.in/604178)

Comment: i was create new thread but still not get an answer, here is my thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266912/always-failed-to-send-image-using-telegram-api-using-php

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH I post you something on [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266912/always-failed-to-send-image-using-telegram-api-using-php) I hope be helpful for you.