# get blank page result when using send image function telegram api on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have create a send image function on native PHP and all works well. here is my simple code :

```
<?php

require 'ApiTelegram.php';

$tele = new ApiTelegram('266009680:AAEvdLIxoXKtLbdBzzJZ6TzAZnYv0');
$path='image/maldini.jpg';
$filename='maldini.jpg';
$chat_id=4234324;

$tess = $tele->sendImage($chat_id,$path,$mime_type='image/jpeg', $filename, $caption='uye');

?>
```

and here is my directory : [image]

problem is, when i want to try implement it on codeigniter, i got blank result. i think this problem caused by wrong image path.

here is my code :

```
public function sendimage()
{

        $path='../../../upload/image/maldini.jpg';
        $file_name= 'maldini.jpg';

        $mime_type='';

        $data = $this->tele->sendImage($this->chat_id,$path, $mime_type, $file_name, $caption='ahay');
        print_r($data); die();

}
```

and here is my directory : 
[image]

i have to try using base_url(), try using "../../" but still not solve my problem.

thanks for any response, :)

Comment: you are using localhost or live sever ?

Comment: localhost sir, when i implement on php native, it work perfect...

Comment: hi do you have this project on github? I'm having trouble with CodeIgniter also, can't even get it to answer back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your path should go just two levels up so you should use two times of `../` . 
And mime type should have a value, then your these lines of your code should change to:

```
$path='../../upload/image/maldini.jpg';
$mime_type='image/jpeg';
```

If it doesn't work use raw [cURL method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358856/6478645)s. If it worked then you have problem with your framework not your bot api.

Comment: got it, my problem solve now. i use realpath function on codeigniter. so i change my code into :  $path=FCPATH.'upload/image/maldini.jpg'; and all works. thanks for your response dude :D